# Tomcat context.xml Parameter declaration accessed in Spring's application context

Tags: java, spring, tomcat, applicationcontext, context.xml

One of our apps declare some parameters in Tomcat's context.xml as such:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context>
    <WatchedResource>WEB-INF/web.xml</WatchedResource>
    <Parameter name="defaultSchema" override="true" value="demo"/>
    <Resource 
         auth="Container" 
         description="DB Connection for Local Jazzee" 
         driverClassName="oracle.jdbc.OracleDriver" 
         . . .
    />
</Context>
```

And then in Spring's applicationContext.xml we are able to use that parameter when we instantiate some beans:

```
<bean id="sessionFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.default_schema">${defaultSchema}</prop>
            . . . 
</bean>
```

And that works fine.

Problem I'm having is that I'm trying to duplicate this in another application, and it's not working.  When I try to start the app, I get the error:

```
Invalid bean definition with name 'sessionFactory' defined in class path resource [db/applicationContext.xml]: Could not resolve placeholder 'defaultSchema'
```

It's the same developer Tomcat instance in both cases, so the Tomcat version is the same.  The Spring library versions appear to be the same as well.  Also, if I hardcode the schema name in the application context, it works fine.  So the dataSource is fine.

Any thoughts on what might be breaking this functionality?

Comment: Can you show tomcat's context.xml definition?

Comment: I added more of the context.xml to the question.  But it's mostly a resource and other Parameters.

Comment: Which `Context.xml` is this in? The global one or the one shipped with your application in the `META-INF` directory? Also make sure that you have defined this property in your `web.xml` as a `resource-ref`.

Comment: It's Tomcat's context.xml.  In the app that works, we don't have any reference to the default schema parameter.